# multiple condition & multiple solution in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, multiple-conditions, multiple-variable-return

Please help if possible.

I want to create a dashboard in excel, where I want to calculate the total sales of the agents in my shift. But the problem is that I want to calculate multiple agent's sale score in a single case as well.

Conditions:

- If in a single sale, there are 3 agents, the sale would be divided among the three with the 3rd person getting 50% of the sale amount and the 1st and the 2nd person both getting 25%.
- If in a single sale, there are 2 agents, the sale would be divided among them equally.
- If a single agent cracks the sale, the amount would belong to him alone.

Now how would I put a formula where these things are calculated automatically?

e.g.:

```
Agent 1     Agent 2     Agent 3    Sale Amount 
Adam                                $100 
Jack         Adam                   $100 
Nick         Vince      Adam        $100 
Vince                               $100
```

According to this, the amount would be as such:

```
Adam: - $100 + $50 + $50 = $200
Jack: - $50 = $50
Nick: - $25 = $25
Vince: - $25 + $100 = $125
```

This is the kind of result I want but want to get it done automatically as soon as the sale is entered. Anyone know how to achieve it through formula?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Thank You! @cybernetic.nomad for making my post more readable!

Comment: Thank You! @Selali Adobor
for the suggested edit!

Comment: Does the number of agent per sale changes or always max at three people?  Do you have more than just those four?

Comment: it will always be either 1 agent or 2 agents or 3 agents. That's it. never more.

I have a total of 6 agents in my team. @Chai Xiong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help you out.  I tested it and it appears to work.
[image: Hope this helps]

Answer (score 0):

You can try following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CHOOSE(MMULT(--($A$2:$C$5<>""),{1;1;1}),{1,0,0},{0.5,0.5,0},{0.25,0.25,0.5})*($A$2:$C$5=G1)*$D$2:$D$5)
```

[image]

if necessary change the ranges automatically in the formula, convert main range to table:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I think that I did not clarify enough...

The array """"($A$2:$C$5<>"")""""       needs to be """"A:C"""" as I need to keep updating it with new sales data....                    Similarly, the array ---->$A$2:$C$f=G1<----       needs to be ---->A:C=G1<----- for the same reason, I need to keep updating it with new sales data...                 Similarly, the array ---->$D$2:$D$5<---- needs to needs to be ---->D:D<----          But when I do that, it doesn't work for me... Can you please check?

Comment: @EvanEmmanuel No, this formula will not work with full column ranges because ```sumproduct``` will not count text in the column headings and ```choose``` will not be able to return the correct value to the empty rows. But it is possible to convert a main range (```A1:D5```) into a table, then, when adding new rows, formula will take them into account. See edit.